# Executing nested <script> tags in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am working on a side project for my website to make the footer more easily editable in the Wordpress theme customizer, and use a dynamic copyright date, something I had in my previous version, but I wanted the values to be more easily editable.

I have created all of this and it works fine, but when I try to add in the dynamic date, it falls over as when I do this, I am trying to have a  within a .

I have looked around quite a bit for an answer to this, but not knowing what to call it doesn't help.

I decided asking my question directly is probably the best thing to do.

So, inside a php script, I have all the values I need which work fine, and a  at the bottom which uses jQuery to append HTML code to a certain area (after the #footer-info area).

I need to be able to use the small amount of code posted below in the area indicated, but have no idea how to do this as it is technically inside a jQuery string.

This is the main  area which I need:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#footer-info").text(' ');
jQuery('<p id="footer-info"><?php if( !empty($footer_one)) : ?><?php echo $footer_one; ?><?php endif; ?> <a href="<?php if( !empty($footer_link_one)) : ?><?php echo $footer_link_one; ?><?php endif; ?>"><?php if( !empty($footer_two)) : ?><?php echo $footer_two; ?><?php endif; ?></a> | &copy; Copyright <?php if( !empty($footer_three)) : ?><?php echo $footer_three; ?><?php endif; ?>**DYNAMIC DATE**<a href="<?php if( !empty($footer_link_two)) : ?><?php echo $footer_link_two; ?><?php endif; ?>"> <?php if( !empty($footer_three)) : ?><?php echo $footer_three; ?><?php endif; ?></a>. All Rights Reserved.</p>').insertAfter("#footer-info");
});
</script>
```

The dynamic date code:

```
<script>new Date().getFullYear()><?php if( !empty($footer_three)) : ?><?php echo $footer_three; ?><?php endif; ?>&&document.write(" - "+new Date().getFullYear());</script>
```

I need a way to put the code above inside the area marked **DYNAMIC DATE** in the first code segment (just past half-way through scrolling).

Is this possible, or am I doing this all wrong?

Here is the whole php file if you need it:

```
<?php

// ====================== Footer Editor ======================

function ds_footer_links_editor($wp_customize) {

    $wp_customize->add_panel( 'footer_links_option', array(
        'priority'       => 30,
        'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',
        'title'          => __('Edit Footer Links', footer_links_title),
        'description'    => __('Customize the login of your website.', footer_links_title),
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_section('ds_footer_links_section', array(
        'priority' => 5,
        'title' => __('Footer Links Editor', footer_links_title),
        'panel'  => 'footer_links_option',
    ));
    // Before Link One
    $wp_customize->add_setting('ds_footer_links_before_link_one', array(
        'default' => 'Designed By',
        'type' => 'option',
        'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_control('ds_footer_links_before_link_one', array(
        'label' => __('Text Before First Link', footer_links_title),
        'section' => 'ds_footer_links_section',
        'type' => 'option',
        'priority' => 5,
        'settings' => 'ds_footer_links_before_link_one'
    ));
    // Link One 
    $wp_customize->add_setting('ds_footer_links_link_one', array(
        'default' => 'Kyle Briggs',
        'type' => 'option',
        'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_control('ds_footer_links_link_one', array(
        'label' => __('First Link Text', footer_links_title),
        'section' => 'ds_footer_links_section',
        'type' => 'option',
        'priority' => 10,
        'settings' => 'ds_footer_links_link_one'
    ));
    // Link One URL 
    $wp_customize->add_setting('ds_footer_link_one_url', array(
        'default' => 'http://kylebriggs.co.uk/',
        'type' => 'option',
        'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_control('ds_footer_link_one_url', array(
        'label' => __('First Link URL', footer_links_title),
        'section' => 'ds_footer_links_section',
        'type' => 'option',
        'priority' => 15,
        'settings' => 'ds_footer_link_one_url'
    ));
    // Company Name
    $wp_customize->add_setting('ds_footer_links_company_name', array(
        'default' => 'Kyle Briggs',
        'type' => 'option',
        'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_control('ds_footer_links_company_name', array(
        'label' => __('Text Before First Link', footer_links_title),
        'section' => 'ds_footer_links_section',
        'type' => 'option',
        'priority' => 5,
        'settings' => 'ds_footer_links_company_name'
    ));
    //Company URL
    $wp_customize->add_setting('ds_footer_link_company_url', array(
        'default' => 'http://kylebriggs.co.uk/',
        'type' => 'option',
        'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_control('ds_footer_link_company_url', array(
        'label' => __('First Link URL', footer_links_title),
        'section' => 'ds_footer_links_section',
        'type' => 'option',
        'priority' => 15,
        'settings' => 'ds_footer_link_company_url'
    ));
    //Start copyright year
    $wp_customize->add_setting('ds_footer_link_start_year', array(
        'default' => '2015',
        'type' => 'option',
        'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_control('ds_footer_link_start_year', array(
        'label' => __('First Link URL', footer_links_title),
        'section' => 'ds_footer_links_section',
        'type' => 'option',
        'priority' => 15,
        'settings' => 'ds_footer_link_start_year'
    ));
}

add_action('customize_register', 'ds_footer_links_editor');

function ds_new_bottom_footer() {

$footer_one = get_option('ds_footer_links_before_link_one','Designed By');
$footer_two = get_option('ds_footer_links_link_one','Kyle Briggs');
$footer_link_one = get_option('ds_footer_link_one_url','http://kylebriggs.co.uk/');
$footer_three = get_option('ds_footer_links_company_name','Kyle Briggs');
$footer_link_two = get_option('ds_footer_link_company_url','http://kylebriggs.co.uk/');
$footer_four = get_option('ds_footer_link_start_year','2015');
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#footer-info").text(' ');
jQuery('<p id="footer-info"><?php if( !empty($footer_one)) : ?><?php echo $footer_one; ?><?php endif; ?> <a href="<?php if( !empty($footer_link_one)) : ?><?php echo $footer_link_one; ?><?php endif; ?>"><?php if( !empty($footer_two)) : ?><?php echo $footer_two; ?><?php endif; ?></a>  | &copy; Copyright <?php if( !empty($footer_three)) : ?><?php echo $footer_three; ?><?php endif; ?><script>new Date().getFullYear()><?php if( !empty($footer_four)) : ?><?php echo $footer_four; ?><?php endif; ?>&&document.write(" - "+new Date().getFullYear());</script> <a href="<?php if( !empty($footer_link_two)) : ?><?php echo $footer_link_two; ?><?php endif; ?>"> <?php if( !empty($footer_three)) : ?><?php echo $footer_three; ?><?php endif; ?></a>. All Rights Reserved.</p>').insertAfter("#footer-info");
});
</script>

<?php
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'ds_new_bottom_footer' );
?>
```

Comment: Why would you use javascript for something that is clearly a php issue? Just add the `<p id="footer-info">` and code you need to `footer.php`. There you can check if the variable is set or empty, and show it, otherwise not. This looks like unnecessary way to add something to your theme...

Comment: @dingo_d I cannot add this to the footer.php file as it would all disappear the second I update that parent theme, I wanted it to be easily editable.

Comment: Well then hook it to `wp_footer` hook as a function `add_action( 'wp_footer', 'your_function' );`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use eval() to execute any script code that you've inserted as DOM text.

MooTools will do this for you automatically, and I'm sure jQuery would as well (depending on the version. jQuery version 1.6+ uses eval). This saves a lot of hassle of parsing out  tags and escaping your content, as well as a bunch of other "gotchas".

Generally if you're going to eval() it yourself, you want to create/send the script code without any HTML markup such as , as these will not eval() properly.

Answer (score 0):

Let we assume, we have following values for those variables.

```
<?php 
$footer_one= "Footer one";
$footer_link_one= "#";
$footer_two = " link";
$footer_three = "Footer three"; 
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#footer-info").html('<?php if( !empty($footer_one)) : ?><?php echo $footer_one; ?><?php endif; ?>'+'<a href="<?php if( !empty($footer_link_one)) : ?><?php echo $footer_link_one; ?><?php endif; ?>"><?php if( !empty($footer_two)) : ?><?php echo $footer_two; ?><?php endif; ?></a> | &copy; Copyright <?php if( !empty($footer_three)) : ?><?php echo $footer_three; ?><?php endif; ?>**DYNAMIC DATE**<a href="<?php if( !empty($footer_link_two)) : ?><?php echo $footer_link_two; ?><?php endif; ?>"> <?php if( !empty($footer_three)) : ?><?php echo $footer_three; ?><?php endif; ?></a>. All Rights Reserved. ');
});
</script>
```

I don't know what below part is doing. Can you explain.

```
<script>new Date().getFullYear()><?php if( !empty($footer_three)) : ?><?php echo $footer_three; ?><?php endif; ?>&&document.write(" - "+new Date().getFullYear());</script>
```